# JAVA calling API succeed but Postman failed

Tags: java, api, postman

I have a JAVA program that calls an API. The API requires body encryption and signing the headers + the body with Hmac256. The source code below returns the desire results. But if I "System.out.print" the header and the body and copy it directly from Java to Postman to make the request, the API returns "signature verification failure" in Postman. Does anybody know what I am missing?

I have included the code and the postman inputs below. Thanks.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
          System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
          HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();
          
          // header
          long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
          HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://example/api/v1");
          String timestamp = String.valueOf(now);
          String nonce = getRandomStringByLength(32);
          httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
          httpPost.setHeader("clientID", clientID);
          httpPost.setHeader("timestamp", timestamp);
          httpPost.setHeader("nonce", nonce);
          
          // body
          JSONObject contentJson = new JSONObject();
          contentJson.put("businessID", getRandomStringByLength(36));
          String[] info = new String[] {"name", "phone", "email"};
          contentJson.put("Fields", info);
          
          // encrypting the body
          JSONObject bodyJson = new JSONObject();
          bodyJson.put("content", encrypt(key,contentJson.toString()));
          String body = bodyJson.toString();
          
          // creating a signature
          String signature = signData(secret,clientID + timestamp + nonce + body);
          
          httpPost.setHeader("signature", signature);
          try {
              StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(body);
              httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);
              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
              if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                  String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                  System.out.println(result);
                  return result;
              }
              String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(httpResponse);
              
          } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e);
              return null;
          }
          return null;
     }
}
```

Postman input:

[headers in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO0Pb.png)

[body in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtWjb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the possibilities are:

- that you have some extra space or new line in the signature pasted in Postman
- that each signature is only accepted once, so if you use it from the Java code, you can't use the same signature again from Postman

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer:) I think the spacing were fine. A signature may indeed be accepted only once! So I have tried not to execute the post request in JAVA if I were to tried it in Postman but it still doesn't work sadly. Thanks anyway:):)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some encoding issue while copy-pasting the data from sysout console via clipboard onto PostMan. When you do a system.out.println, you may not get the correct value if the source string encoding and sysout console's recognized encoding is different.

Comment: Oh this one is very likely!!!! Thank you so much for such a useful explanation:) If that's the case, do you know anyway that I can solve this problem cause by the difference in the encoding methods? Many Thanks:):)